# SQL < any <= any returns same thing

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table College(cName varchar(100), state varchar(100), enrollment int);
insert into College values ('Stanford', 'CA', 15000);
insert into College values ('Berkeley', 'CA', 36000);
insert into College values ('MIT', 'MA', 10000);
insert into College values ('Cornell', 'NY', 21000);


select cName 
from College S1 
where enrollment <= any (select enrollment 
                             from College S2 
                             where S2.cName <> S1.cName)

select cName 
from College S1 
where enrollment < any (select enrollment
                        from College S2 
                        where S2.cName <> S1.cName)
```

[image]

These 2 queries return the same thing and I don't understand why.  The first query is also not returning Berkeley but isn't Berkeley <= Berkeley.

Comment: You have a correlation clause that prevents a row from being compared to itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is S2.cName <> S1.cName referring to a joined table of S1 and S2?

Comment: Not joined I meant cross product

Comment: Please, provide source data. It is hard to tell why you have some results without knowlege of what is the source of it. And there's no `'Berkeley' <= 'Berkeley'` comparison.

Comment: @astentx What do you mean by source data?  Do you need something else besides the Screenshot of table?

Comment: @bakalolo I mean you should post your original data and the results in text format. If both query returns the same, you of course can post only one result. Please, check [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) for more information.

Comment: There are no two rows with the same enrollment but a different cname in your sample data, so the `=` in `<=` never applies.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing enrollment values for matching cNames by doing `where S2.cName <> S1.cName`

Ignore this condition to see the difference:

```
select cName 
from College S1 
where enrollment <= any (select enrollment from College S2)

select cName 
from College S1 
where enrollment < any (select enrollment from College S2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when it comes to Berkeley there is no value which is <= 36000(corresponding enrollment value)
ie 36000<=(15000,10000,21000) which won't return anything